# chapterbib sort in the order of appearance

Tags: natbib, chapterbib

I am trying to sort bibliography for the Springer svmono class using the spbasic style. Springer recommends chapterbib for chapterwise bibliography. I need to sort the references in the order of their appearance.

The other answers suggest editing the spbasic style file. I did that, but that does not work either. In fact, you can use unsrtnat instead of spbasic in the following example and still get alphabetically sorted references.

Here is a minimal working example (test.tex):

```
\documentclass[english,graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@Article{Schauer2005,
  author    = {T. Schauer and N. O. Neg{\aa}rd and F. Previdi and K. J. Hunt and M. H. Fraser and E. Ferchland and J. Raisch},
  title     = {Online identification and nonlinear control of the electrically stimulated quadriceps muscle},
  journal   = {Control Eng. Pract.},
  year      = {2005},
  volume    = {13},
  number    = {9},
  pages     = {1207--1219},
  month     = sep,
  timestamp = {2017-07-12},
}
@Article{Seel.Werner.ea2016,
  author    = {Thomas Seel and Cordula Wener and J{\"{o}}rg Raisch and Thomas Schauer},
  title     = {Iterative Learning Control of a Drop Foot Neuroprosthesis - Generating Physiological Foot Motion in Paretic Gait by Automatic Feedback Control},
  journal   = {Control Eng. Pract.},
  year      = {2016},
  volume    = {48},
  pages     = {87--97},
  month     = mar,
  timestamp = {2017-07-12},
}
@Article{Wang.Saberi.ea2013,
  Title      = {Consensus in the network with uniform constant communication delay},
  Author     = {Xu Wang and Ali Saberi and Anton A. Stoorvogel and H{\r{a}}vard Fj{\ae}r Grip and Tao Yang},
  Journal    = {Automatica},
  Year       = {2013},
  Pages      = {2461--2467},
  Volume     = {49},
  Timestamp  = {2014.08.25}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Chapter1.tex}
\chapter{Chapter1}
Some claim (see, e.g., \cite{Wang.Saberi.ea2013}, \cite{Seel.Werner.ea2016}, and \cite{Schauer2005})
\begin{btSect}[spbasic]{ref}
\btPrintCited
\end{btSect}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Chapter2.tex}
\chapter{Chapter2}
Some claim (see, e.g., \cite{Seel.Werner.ea2016,Schauer2005,Wang.Saberi.ea2013})
\begin{btSect}[spbasic]{ref}
\btPrintCited
\end{btSect}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage[dot]{bibtopic}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}

\author{Author name(s)}

\title{Book title}

\maketitle
\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this on windows, i.e.,

```
pdflatex test
bibtex test.1
bibtex test.2
pdflatex test
pdflatex test
```

I get

> Some claim (see, e.g., [3], [2], and [1])

in Chapter 1. I am expecting

> Some claim (see, e.g., [1], [2], and [3])

instead.
How do I get the references to sort in the order of appearance?

I am convinced that my modifications to spbasic are correct because the following code works as expected (same ref.bib as above):

```
\begin{filecontents}{Chapter1.tex}
\chapter{Chapter1}
Some claim (see, e.g., \cite{Wang.Saberi.ea2013}, \cite{Seel.Werner.ea2016}, and \cite{Schauer2005})
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Chapter2.tex}
\chapter{Chapter2}
Some claim (see, e.g., \cite{Seel.Werner.ea2016,Schauer2005,Wang.Saberi.ea2013})
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,sectionbib]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\author{Author name(s)}

\title{Book title}

\maketitle
\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2}
\bibliographystyle{spbasic-unsrt}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

That is, my spbasic-unsrt.bst sorts the references in the order of their appearance as long as the bibliography is global. As soon as I add bibtopic and chapterbib to get chapterwise bibliography, the sorting reverts back to alphabetical.

Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. The bibtopic package does not support unsorted bibliography. Also, bibtopic is not needed to get chapterwise bibliography. Chapterbib works just fine. The following code yields expected behavior:

```
\documentclass[english,graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@Article{Schauer2005,
  author    = {T. Schauer and N. O. Neg{\aa}rd and F. Previdi and K. J. Hunt and M. H. Fraser and E. Ferchland and J. Raisch},
  title     = {Online identification and nonlinear control of the electrically stimulated quadriceps muscle},
  journal   = {Control Eng. Pract.},
  year      = {2005},
  volume    = {13},
  number    = {9},
  pages     = {1207--1219},
  month     = sep,
  timestamp = {2017-07-12},
}
@Article{Seel.Werner.ea2016,
  author    = {Thomas Seel and Cordula Wener and J{\"{o}}rg Raisch and Thomas Schauer},
  title     = {Iterative Learning Control of a Drop Foot Neuroprosthesis - Generating Physiological Foot Motion in Paretic Gait by Automatic Feedback Control},
  journal   = {Control Eng. Pract.},
  year      = {2016},
  volume    = {48},
  pages     = {87--97},
  month     = mar,
  timestamp = {2017-07-12},
}
@Article{Wang.Saberi.ea2013,
  Title      = {Consensus in the network with uniform constant communication delay},
  Author     = {Xu Wang and Ali Saberi and Anton A. Stoorvogel and H{\r{a}}vard Fj{\ae}r Grip and Tao Yang},
  Journal    = {Automatica},
  Year       = {2013},
  Pages      = {2461--2467},
  Volume     = {49},
  Timestamp  = {2014.08.25}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Chapter1.tex}
\chapter{Chapter1}
Some claim (see, e.g., \cite{Wang.Saberi.ea2013}, \cite{Seel.Werner.ea2016}, and \cite{Schauer2005})
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Chapter2.tex}
\chapter{Chapter2}
Some claim (see, e.g., \cite{Seel.Werner.ea2016,Schauer2005,Wang.Saberi.ea2013})
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}

\author{Author name(s)}

\title{Book title}

\maketitle
\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2}
\end{document}
```